# Firebase - Failing to install firebase using npm but yarn works

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, npm-install

```
λ npm -g install firebase
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...9gwBD9c+ThTWWmNBXcfJZ'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\2nchy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-13T18_19_46_173Z-debug.log
```

I increased timeout seconds in **.npmrc to 12,000** and downgraded **npm to 6.3.17**, cleared the cache as it was suggested and even **installed it from an empty directory** but still getting an almost same error

**UPDATE**
Uninstalled nodejs and resinstalled. This is the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'firebase'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose npm-session 73d31a98f2671f49
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase 5152ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for firebase@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....0"},"dist":{"shasum"'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 5197ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....0"},"dist":{"shasum"'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\2nchy\Desktop\firetrial
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "firebase"
15 verbose node v12.16.3
16 verbose npm  v6.14.4
17 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....0"},"dist":{"shasum"'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem; it arised for me because I was using different package managers in the same project **yarn** and **npm**
Using either one of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I just had to upgrade npm to the latest version instead of downgrading it.

- `npm install -g npm@latest`
- and because of a slow internet connection, i kept `timeout=12000` in .npmrc
- This issue might help: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1185#issuecomment-641990197

Answer (score 0):

Using a registry mirror is what worked for me

npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org

Then after the installation i switched back to

npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org